Calculate the sum of natural numbers
How to calculate the sum of the following natural rows:
1+2+3+4+5
1+2+3+4
1+2+3
1+2
1
In this case the sum is 35. Is there a general formula for any natural sequence of such pattern?

I don't know but I can't help noticing that this is the same sum as 11111+2222+333+44+5.

It depends a bit what you mean - since when you get to n=10 you have to define the form you want.

Welcome to Math SE! I would recommend being a bit clearer in questions like these, and/or adding what you tried yourself.

Edit, I didn't write it correctly. I need to sum lists of naturals all starting from 1. So if n = 3, then I sum 1+  1+2  +1+2+3

@Please also edit your question itself to include that correction.

First notice that $12345...k=1×10^{k-1}+2×10^{k-2}+....+k×10^{k-k}$
Now we have to sum it from $k=1$ to $k=n$ and let's call the sum as $S$
Add all the numbers term by term and we'll get $$S=10^{n-1}(1)+10^{n-2}(1+2)+\cdots+10^{n-n}(1+2+3+\cdots+n)$$
$$\implies S=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(10^{n-i}\left(\sum_{j=1}^i j\right)\right)$$
$$\implies S=\frac{10^n}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{i^2}{10^i}+\frac{i}{10^i}\right)\right)$$
Both of the above summations can be solved by using the concept of AGP (Arithmetic and Geometric Progession) and the final answer will be $$\boxed{S=\frac{200(10^n-1)-81n^2-261n}{1458}}$$
You can verify it too.

Please see edit

I am assuming you are asking for sums of the form $12345+1234+123+12+1$, for the first term being of n digits($n=5$ in this case). So, we may rewrite the sum as:
$(1\cdot10^{n-1}+2\cdot 10^{n-2}+...+(n-1)\cdot 10^{1}+n\cdot10^0)+(1\cdot10^{n-2}+2\cdot 10^{n-3}+...+(n-2)\cdot 10^{1}+(n-1)\cdot10^0)+...$
This may be rearranged and rewritten as:
$1\cdot(10^{n-1}+10^{n-2}+..10^1+1)+2\cdot(10^{n-2}+10^{n-3}+..+10^1+1)+3\cdot (10^{n-3}+..+10+1)+...+(n-1)\cdot(10+1)+n\cdot(1)$
$=(1)(10^{n-1})+(1+2)(10^{n-2})+(1+2+3)(10^{n-3})+...+(1+2+...+(n-1))(10)+(1+2+..+n)(1)$
$=(1)(10^{n-1})+\frac{2\cdot 3}{2}(10^{n-2})+\frac{3\cdot 4}{2}(10^{n-3})+...+\frac{(n-1)\cdot n}{2}(10)+\frac{n\cdot (n+1)}{2}(1)$
$=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k\cdot (k+1)}{2}\cdot 10^{n-k}=\frac{-81n^2-261n+200(10^n-1)}{1458}$.
I leave it in this form to conclude.

This is the answer to the edited question.
Let's call the sum as $S$.
This is a series whose first term is $1$, second term is $1+2$, third term is $1+2+3$ and so on and the $n$th term is $1+2+3+\cdots n$
So we can say that the $i$th term of this series is $1+2+3+\cdots i$ or $\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$
Now since we have to sum all the terms from $i=1$ to $i=n$, we have $$S=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i(i+1)}{2}$$
$$\implies \boxed{S=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}}$$
by using the facts that 
$\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ 
$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Could you elaborate on how you transformed the sum of sums to the final formula and how you get 6 in the denominator
